# querySelectorAll not working to find classes that end with text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like a JS function to remove a class from any div that has a class name ending with a specific value.

Here's my example:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class$="-lvl1"]');

elements.forEach(element => {
    element.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="A-lvl1 hidden">
A
</div>
<div class="B-lvl1 hidden">
B
</div>
<div class="C-lvl1 hidden">
C
</div>
<div class="D-lvl2 hidden">
D
</div>
```

I would like the "hidden" class removed from any element that has has a classname ending in "-lvl1".  Currently querySelectorAll does not return any elements.

I have tried printing the output of "elements" to the console, but it does not return any.  If I try to select a specific class querySelectorAll('.A-lvl1'), it works, so I presume there is an issue with the selector ('[class$=-lvl1]')

I'm expecting all of the "-lvl1" divs to appear after the code runs, as the "hidden" class should be removed.

Comment: Assuming that class names will appear in the space-separated `.className` property in any particular order is a very fragile coding practice. My strong preference is to use a separate class to categorize; you can have as many classes as you want, after all.  Then you can use `.lvl1` or whatever instead of relying on the `-lvl1` class to be the last classname in the list.

Comment: Please don't provide links to your code at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Instead, just create a Stack Snippet when you are editing your question (click the <> button to enter the Stack Snippet) and you can create executable code right here (I have done this for you on this question).

Comment: So does the [class$="-lvl1"] return only the elements that actually END with that string in a series of classes?  I must have mistakenly thought that it would look for any element that contains a class with that text.

Comment: `[class$="-lvl1"]` attempts to match the entire class string, and looks for it to end with `-lvl1` which none of your examples do. If you change `<div class="A-lvl1 hidden">` to `<div class="hidden A-lvl1">` it will work

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the replies.  I mistakenly thought that it would look for any element that has a class ending with the specified string, not that the specified string would be at the end of the class list.

Comment: The better solution is not to store state in your DOM, but instead update the DOM based on state changes to in-memory objects. Doing fuzzy searches against things like the `class` attribute is brittle and slow.

Comment: If you are developing this, it would make more sense to probably use data attributes and not a class if the level class has zero to do with style. Not sure how you are actually using it so I can't give a great answer on how to solve your problem.

Comment: @epascarello: you are right, I'm only using the class as an identifier so that I can find the objects to work on.  I guess I could use the ID instead and use an [id$="-lvl2"] selector.  If I were to use the data attribute, how would I search for any instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the order of your classes, you should be using `*=` in your selector, rather than `$=` because your `class` attributes actually end with `hidden`. The [`*=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) allows for matching against values that contain the specified string. **But note that using this wildcard search could wind up matching on classes you didn't intend to match.**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class*="-lvl1"]').forEach(element => {
    element.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="A-lvl1 hidden">A</div>
<div class="B-lvl1 hidden">B</div>
<div class="C-lvl1 hidden">C</div>
<div class="D-lvl2 hidden">D</div>
```

You could also just swap the order of the class names so that `hidden` is listed first and then use `$=`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[class$="-lvl1"]').forEach(element => {
    element.classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="hidden A-lvl1">A</div>
<div class="hidden B-lvl1">B</div>
<div class="hidden C-lvl1">C</div>
<div class="hidden D-lvl2">D</div>
```

Comment: hopefully OP does not have `"X-lvl11"`

Comment: It should be noted that `*=` does not do what was requested. It will match things like `A-lvl10`.

Comment: @epascarello & user229044 Answer updated to note this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data attribute with ends with and not a class

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-id$="-lvl1"]').forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute("hidden")
});
```

```html
<div data-id="A-lvl1" hidden>A</div>
<div data-id="B-lvl1" hidden>B</div>
<div data-id="C-lvl1" hidden>C</div>
<div data-id="D-lvl2" hidden>D</div>
```

You could break it up into just the levels

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-level="1"]').forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute("hidden")
});
```

```html
<div data-group="A" data-level="1" hidden>A</div>
<div data-group="B" data-level="1" hidden>B</div>
<div data-group="C" data-level="1" hidden>C</div>
<div data-group="D" data-level="2" hidden>D</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no selector which will target elements containing at least one class name having a specific suffix. However, you can use a short series of steps to find such elements.

First, you can use the [wildcard equality attribute selector (`*=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_6) to initially select elements which contain the suffix in the `class` attribute. Then, for each candidate element, iterate over its [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to determine if one [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) the target suffix.

> You could also use a regular expression (e.g. [`/-lvl1\s*/`](https://regexr.com/7ir3b)) to [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) the entire `class` attribute string instead of the iteration/`endsWith` approach.

Below is a functional example:

```js
function findElementsWithClassNameSuffix(suffix, rootNode = window.document) {
  const elements = [];
  for (
    const element of rootNode.querySelectorAll(
      `[class*=${JSON.stringify(suffix)}]`,
    )
  ) {
    for (const className of element.classList) {
      if (className.endsWith(suffix)) {
        elements.push(element);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return elements;
}

for (const element of findElementsWithClassNameSuffix("-lvl1")) {
  element.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="A-lvl1 hidden">A</div>
<div class="B-lvl1 hidden">B</div>
<div class="C-lvl1 hidden">C</div>
<div class="D-lvl2 hidden">D</div>
```

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGYAmBRANgUwLY5hQDOA6jFABYDCWAhscQHJ0EDKIwKAHgBQBQiRMU48AXMKgAnVAHMANIMRS4cKEzhocEgAp0phdZpyIAvIgDuqNHAsA6GxBAEiigJQTs+QwG0AuogA3koQCMRQiDi4LiSe0b4B5v4A3ErAcFKIAkJCoWDhkfFEiHDAyqpGWnYAjiA4UgCebFE40BkAglhY2TlCAAY+EPSMAFSmACSBAFJsAPJMduEyYLIwwA28Ilww3G4Avn59ir1uSm5BSkLpmbx5BUMMzKwmpYXeRHYPjAAyMOHnwV6QjWWS+TwIdkIaDIFEom1EOzcAMuQJaMWIdgADiBiHC0YY3KkgTkAEYGOgAayJQL2KNpQnpyhwUBAUiQ+KIxFStP411BYQiHIirxQ6C86PIVFojxY7ARfAARABaLAANywAEYFUiLkIhZ9hsRfuE7AY8HBVTheArKDA0FowNrufwgA)